# How to properly grow and shrink div with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've figured out how to show and hide a div with radio buttons. However I also want the main div to grow and shrink depending on which value is selected to make room for more questions. The issue I'm having is if you click the yes option multiple times, the form grows and grows forever. and if you click no multiple times it shrinks to nothing.

I'm looking for a way to set a boolean that will only allow the form to grow once when yes if clicked and shrink once when no is clicked. I've attached some example code.

```js
toggle();

function toggle() {
  var optionA = document.getElementById("yes");
  var optionB = document.getElementById("no");
  var question = document.getElementById("moreQuestions");
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var height = form.offsetHeight;
  var newHeight = height + 200;
  var oldHeight = height - 200;

  // the condition checks: is option A is selected?
  if (optionA.checked) {
    // if "yes" is selected, then the question is shown
    // no input ("") uses the default display
    question.style.display = "";
    form.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
  } else if (optionB.checked) {
    form.style.height = oldHeight + 'px';
    question.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // question is hidden if the "none" option is selected
    question.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.form {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 240, 0.733);
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.radio {
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.select-box {
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="form" id="form">
  <div class="radio"><label>Show More?</label><br>
    <label><input id="yes" name="radio1" type="radio"  value="yes" onclick="toggle()" required="" />Yes</label><br>
    <label><input id="no" name="radio1" type="radio" value="no" onclick="toggle()" required="" />No</label><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="moreQuestions">
    <select class="select-box">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select><br><br>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: If the form's height should change based on what's added/removed/visible/not visible, why are you explicitly setting `height` anyway? Just stop doing it

Comment: How about instead of manually changing height and width, you put 2 different classes for different states and switch the elements class around ?

Comment: This is a simplified example. There are multiple questions that should perform this action. also height is required because I need to add `overflow:hidden;` as there is a second form outside the box which the user can toggle to, like a Sign-up/Register setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need replace `onclick()` event to `onchange()`. Also, i got an error while replicate your code. Created two functions for easy to use, for **adding** and **removing** heights.

```js
const optionA = document.getElementById('yes');
const optionB = document.getElementById('no');
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const question = document.getElementById('moreQuestions');
const expandHeight = 200;

const adding = () => {
  // Get current form height
  const formHeight = form.offsetHeight;
  question.style.display = '';
  // Set style with height added
  form.style.height = `${formHeight + expandHeight}px`;
};

const removing = () => {
  // Get current form height
  const formHeight = form.offsetHeight;
  question.style.display = 'none';
  // Set style with height removed
  form.style.height = `${formHeight - expandHeight}px`;
};

optionA.addEventListener('change', adding);
optionB.addEventListener('change', removing);
```

```css
.form {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% auto;
  background: rgba(253, 167, 141, 0.733);
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.radio {
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.select-box {
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="form" id="form">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>Show More?</label><br />
    <label>
          <input
            id="yes"
            name="radio1"
            type="radio"
            value="yes"
            required=""
          />Yes
        </label>
    <br />
    <label>
          <input id="no" name="radio1" type="radio" value="no" required="" />No
        </label>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="moreQuestions">
    <select class="select-box">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would be something simple. I'm still learning.

Comment: This works great when its just yes or no. However if there is a question with options 1,2,3, and 4. Lets say 1,2 and 3 would cause it to grow but 4 would not. I still get the same issue when changing from 1 to 2 or 3. Hmmm

Comment: In this case you need to create **loop** of inputs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do that. I can just change the form layout to a simpler design for now. Thank you